# How to fix 'Cannot find module 'external-editor'

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a new ionic project but I'm getting these error "Cannot find module 'external-editor'"

I have already installed npm and nodejs.
npm version is 6.7.0
nodejs version v8.11.2

I've also installed ionic using this command "npm install -g ionic"

How can I resolve that error?

Answer (score 0):

This command installs the external-editor module globally:

```
npm install -g external-editor
```